# Is there an equivalent of Java NavigableSet object in Objective-c?

Tags: java, ios, objective-c

I' looking for an equivalent of Java `NavigableSet` object in objective-C, especially to get the pollFirst method.

Any ideas ?

EDIT :
Documentation of NavigableSet : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html

> A SortedSet extended with navigation methods reporting closest matches for given search targets.
>
> This interface additionally defines methods pollFirst and pollLast that return and remove the lowest and highest element, if one exists, else returning null.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: what does `NavigableSet ` exactly does?

Comment: I see that there are lots of methods that inherit `NavigableSet`? Can you list few whose equivalent you need.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I actually only need the pollFirst() method

Comment: `PollFirst` is implemented on Linked Lists..On which kind of property you want to implement it in iOS?

Comment: I have not decided yet, the best would probably be on NSOrderedSet, don't you think so ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826789/getting-an-object-from-an-nsset.... By the way i know you want to know some general answer, but I didn't found any equivalent.

Comment: Yes ok, I had seen that, I was hoping that some magician would know a solution :) Thanks anyway